# div not clickable after isotope filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, show, jquery-isotope

I've successfully implemented a filter using the jQuery isotope plugin which filters out the content accordingly. The only problem is that the click functions attached to the filtered content no longer work after the filter has been implemented.
Here's my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('#projectimages');

jQuerycontainer.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.shown',
    animationEngine: 'css',
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: 2
    }
});

jQuery('#menu a').click(function(){
    var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
    jQuerycontainer.isotope({ filter: selector });
  return false;
});
});


jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery(".hidden").hide();
jQuery(".pics-hidden").hide();

jQuery('.wp-image-111').click(function() {
      jQuery('.post-98').addClass('shown').removeClass('hidden').delay(300).fadeIn(100);
      jQuery('#projectimages').isotope('reloadItems').isotope();
       });       
});
```

After the filter has been implemented, the click functions attached to ('.wp-image-111') no longer works, is there a reason for this? If so is there a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery('#post-'+jQuery(this).attr('larget'))
.removeClass('shown')
.addClass('.hidden')
  ---------^
.removeClass('#post-'+jQuery(this)
.attr('larget')).hide();
```

should be

```
 jQuery('.close').click(function() {
   jQuery('#post-'+jQuery(this).attr('larget'))
    .removeClass('shown')
    .addClass('hidden');
   jQuery('#post-'+jQuery(this).attr('larget')).attr("id","");
```

});

you cannot remove id.

Comment: Thank you, but it hasn't solved the problem, closing the divs works fine, but clicking to open them doesn't seem to be working after I have implemented the isotope filter?

Comment: *bump* anyone have any idea? Can't figure out why it's not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you haven't applied the recommended CSS; I didn't and the links on my filters only went to items that were hidden (due them still being there and on top I guess!) - they now work after applying these:

```
/**** Isotope filtering ****/

.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```